# using sep argumnt to put double rounded parenthesis

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, parentheses

I would like to close in double parenthesis the second column I am trying to unite

```
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg), 
            sd = sd(mpg)) %>% 
  tidyr::unite('A', 1:2, sep = ' (')
```

On this purpose I am using the `sep argument` but I do not know whether it is possible somehow or not using this method. If not could you please provide some other example?

This is the desired output

```
                           A
1 20.090625 (6.0269480520891)
```

Comment: It print than sign between the values I am attacching

Answer (score 3):

I think `paste`, `sprintf`, and `glue` are all more natural choices than `unite` for this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg), 
            sd = sd(mpg)) %>% 
  mutate(
    paste = paste0(mean, " (", sd, ")"),
    sprintf = sprintf("%s (%s)", mean, sd),
    glue = glue("{mean} ({sd})")
  )
#       mean       sd                      paste                     sprintf
# 1 20.09062 6.026948 20.090625(6.0269480520891) 20.090625 (6.0269480520891)
#                          glue
# 1 20.090625 (6.0269480520891)
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am using unite() because I would like to drop out the step of creating new columns

Comment: @12666727b9 you are creating a new column `A` with `unite`.  This answer shows multiple ways of accomplishing what you are trying to do. You can pick anyone and replace the left hand side with `A`. Also, you can specify `.keep` argument of `mutate` to drop columns you don't need/don't use.

Comment: Just an FYI to OP or any other users, if you already have the `stringr` package attached, you can use `str_glue` which is just a wrapper of `glue::glue`.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, a minor follow up question. I always use glue in such cases. Would sprintf have a specific use in which it is superior to glue?

Comment: @GuedesBF you can easily specify the number of decimal places/number of characters/left adjust/rightadjust ect in `sprintf`. Can you do so in `glue`?? eg how would `sprintf("%-3s is %03d values from %.3f", "H", 3, 3.5)` How will its glue code look like?

Comment: `sprintf` is part of base, so has no dependencies. That can be a pretty strong advantage in certain use cases. And, as Onyambu points out, `sprintf` essentially has the `formatC` interface built-in, which is powerful (and arcane). But I generally prefer the `glue` interface as well.

Comment: @Onyambu you can specify any function with the curly braces. It may not be as compact as `sprintf` but it can be easy to understand and flexible. If you had those values stored in a column or as global variables `x`, `y`, `z`: `library(stringr); str_glue("{str_pad(x, 3, 'right')} is a {str_pad(y, 3, 'left', 0)} values from {format(z, nsmall = 3)}")`

Comment: @LMc Thanks. we both agree that not as compact. I do use glue at times, but still prefer sprintf due to its compactness, and in my mind i consider `sprintf` to be somewhat superior. thats what I was trying to respond to @GuedesBF. Hope R manages to include something similar to string format in python.

Answer (score 0):

just add the parentheses before unite

```r
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg), 
            sd = sd(mpg)) %>% 
  mutate(sd = paste0('(', sd, ')')) %>% 
  tidyr::unite('A', 1:2, sep = ' ')
```